# Alternative way to map object key values

Tags: javascript

What is the alternative/best way to map through an object key-values without using `forEach`?

This is what I have currently:

```
sortObject(source) {
    const object = Object.assign({}, source);

    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
      // Sort array by priority (the higher the number, the higher the priority)
      object[key] = object[key].sort((a, b) => b.priority - a.priority);

      // Limit the array length to the 5
      if (object[key].length > 5) {
        object[key] = object[key].slice(0, 5);
      }
    });

    return object;
}
```

`source` is an object like:

```
{
  base: [
    { id: 1, priority: 5 },
    { id: 2, priority: 10 },
    { id: 3, priority: 1 },
    { id: 4, priority: 5 },
    { id: 5, priority: 15 }
  ],
  extra: [
    { id: 1, priority: 1 },
    { id: 2, priority: 5 },
    { id: 3, priority: 10 }
  ],
  additional: [
    { id: 1, priority: 5 },
    { id: 2, priority: 10 },
    { id: 3, priority: 10 },
    { id: 4, priority: 15 },
    { id: 5, priority: 1 },
    { id: 6, priority: 29 },
    { id: 7, priority: 100 },
    { id: 8, priority: 100 },
    { id: 9, priority: 5 }
  ]
}
```

The final output is like:

```
{
  base: [
    { id: 5, priority: 15 },
    { id: 2, priority: 10 },
    { id: 1, priority: 5 },
    { id: 4, priority: 5 },
    { id: 3, priority: 1 }
  ],
  extra: [
    { id: 3, priority: 10 },
    { id: 2, priority: 5 },
    { id: 1, priority: 1 }
  ],
  additional: [
    { id: 7, priority: 100 },
    { id: 8, priority: 100 },
    { id: 6, priority: 29 },
    { id: 4, priority: 15 },
    { id: 2, priority: 10 }
  ]
}
```

is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the *actual* input, rather than placeholder empty objects, so we have a [MCVE] to play with?

Comment: @CertainPerformance sure! give me a second

Comment: You can use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: Also, note that `sort` works **in place**, so no need for `object[key] = object[key].sort(...)`. And any time you find yourself repeating something like `object[key]` over and over, it suggests you might want to put it in a variable and reuse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd look at [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (new as of ES2017 but polyfillable) and destructuring in a `for-of` loop.

If nothing else has access to the arrays on `source` (which I tend to assume, since `sort` works *in-place*, so the code already modifies the original array; but at the same time, `source` is coming in from outside, so...):

```
sortObject(source) {
    const object = Object.assign({}, source);

    for (const [key, array] of Object.entries(object)) {
        array.sort((a, b) => b.priority - a.priority);
        array.length = Math.min(array.length, 5);
    }

    return object;
}
```

If something else has access to those arrays and you shouldn't modify them other than sorting them, then you'll need your original `length` check and `slice`:

```
sortObject(source) {
    const object = Object.assign({}, source);

    for (const [key, array] of Object.entries(object)) {
        array.sort((a, b) => b.priority - a.priority);
        if (array.length > 5) {
            object[key] = array.slice(0, 5);
        }
    }

    return object;
}
```

Your code suggests you may not have realized `sort` works in-place since you were assigning the result back to the original location. If so and you didn't intend to sort the arrays in-place, you'll need to copy the arrays before sorting:

```
sortObject(source) {
    const object = Object.assign({}, source);

    for (const [key, array] of Object.entries(object)) {
        object[key] = array = array.slice();
        array.sort((a, b) => b.priority - a.priority);
        array.length = Math.min(array.length, 5);
    }

    return object;
}
```

You could replace

```
        object[key] = array = array.slice();
        array.sort((a, b) => b.priority - a.priority);
```

with

```
        object[key] = array = Array.from(array).sort((a, b) => b.priority - a.priority);
```

if you like, but that'll use an iterator, which is more overhead than `slice`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use map for looping the object entries and splice for cutting off the array length:

```
const getSortedObj = (source) => {
    let obj = Object.assign({}, source);
    Object.entries(obj).map( entry => {
        let [key, arr] = entry;
        arr.sort((a, b) => b.priority - a.priority).splice(Math.min(arr.length, 5));
        return entry;
    });
    return obj;
};
```

Comment: This is a misuse of `map`. `map` builds and returns an array. If you're not using `map`'s return value (the array it builds) and don't want to use `for-of`, use `forEach`.

Comment: I do not agree. Why is this a missue of map? and the question is  What is the alternative/best way to map through an object key-values without using forEach?

Comment: I said why in my comment above: You're not using the array it creates, so having it create that array is pointless. See MDN: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Note that none of the `map` examples fail to use the array it returns. You're using a screwdriver to hammer a nail. Use a hammer instead.